# Possession and Masquerade - are these too powerful in 2 player games?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue, dominion-alchemy

Just encountered this yesterday.

- Player A plays [Possession](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=possession)
- Then, it's player B turn (with player A deciding), and there's a [Masquerade](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=masquerade) in the hand.
- Player A decides to play the Masquerade,
- Player A chooses the card to swap in both hands!
- *Swapping a province for a curse is so delightful.*

But also it seems too much powerful. Am I doing something wrong?

*Note that it does not work with 3 players or more, because of the rotation of the swapped cards between the 3 players.*

Comment: As keithjgrant said,  it's not an overpowered combo because the player B could have simply chosen to not buy a Masquerade.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possession and Masquerade are just known to be wacky when used together.  That's just what happens when you have 100+ cards at this point.  Donald X. Vaccarino [said](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/4910970#4910970) "Possession is a case where Masquerade ends up being a weird exception", but it's basically not worth special rules or changing the card for this one interaction.

keithjgrant is also right that if Possession is out, you'd better not buy Masquerade. :)

Comment: What? Where did Donald admit that this combo is broken? Buying Masquerade (or Ambassador) when Possession is on the board is a risky move. You don't have to buy the Masquerade. And if you are able to use Masquerade to give your opponent a Masquerade, all while having the type of deck where you can play enough Possession to use it on your opponent's turn, then you probably have a deck that could win either way. This most certainly is not a broken combo.

Comment: Man, this was a long time ago... I might have been referring to http://boardgamegeek.com/article/4910970#4910970, perhaps? "Broken" is probably too strong a word, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Wow, sorry, didn't notice the date on this! It showed up on the front page because the question was edited. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 8):

The only person doing something wrong is the one who buys a Masquerade into their deck while Possession is on the table!  You can also do a similar thing with Ambassador.

Answer (score 1):

Masquerade is a powerful card, but buying it in a game with Possession is of course a big risk. (Even in a 3p game, if you get a lead, an opponent who Possesses you might have you pass a Province to an opponent who's not doing so well.) If there are Cursing attacks that will make it difficult to assemble the $6 + Potion cost, Masquerade can be worth that risk since it will also help dispose of Curses.